# Getting Response status code does not indicate success: 500 if file is too large

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, iis-7, dotnet-httpclient

I am trying to send a large chunk of XML data (~10mb) using `HttpClient` to my local IIS server, but always getting 500 error:  `Response status code does not indicate success: 500`:

```
StringContent content = new StringContent(xmlData, Encoding.UTF8, "application/xml");

var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, redirectedAddress) { Content = content };

HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        client.SendAsync(request).ContinueWith(
          postTask =>
          {
              var status = postTask.Result.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
          });
```

So `EnsureSuccessStatusCode` method throws me the 500 error, however if I will send a file much smaller, something like 50kb, it works with no problem.

I did some research, and people suggest to increase the max size of data in my IIS configuration, so I did:

```
<system.web>
<compilation targetFramework="4.5" />
<httpRuntime executionTimeout="360" 
             maxRequestLength="65536"
             useFullyQualifiedRedirectUrl="false"
             minFreeThreads="8"
             minLocalRequestFreeThreads="4"
             appRequestQueueLimit="100"
             enableVersionHeader="true" />
```

and

```
<system.webServer>
<security >
  <requestFiltering>
    <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="1000000000000" />
  </requestFiltering>
</security>
</system.webServer>
```

But still no luck, once the size of data is getting larger than 5mb, I get the exception. Is there anything else I need to setup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to increase maxRequestLength as well. Currently it is set to 65536 which is around 6 mb, you need to double that for your need. See this for detail: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.configuration.httpruntimesection.maxrequestlength(v=vs.110).aspx